# Using command line output in batch script

Tags: batch-file, networking, window, azure-active-directory, command-prompt

I'm reasonably new to using batch scripts - and essentially I want a way to be able to resolve an active directory domain name on a machine, store it in a text file and then ping that address? I might be doing this the long way around as there might be a much easier to do it! But my logic at the moment was to export nslookup to a txt file and then ping the first line of nslookup.txt (after the first 9 characters where it says "address: " or something similar, and then store that in a text file too!

if im massively overcomplicating things please let me know!

Connor

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for /f` to get the desired value into a variable:

```
set "adr="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('echo exit^|nslookup') do if not defined adr set "adr=%%A"
ping %adr% > file.txt
```

Note: the value of the `%adr%` variable has two leading spaces, but they don't disturb with the `ping` command. If you want to remove them, use `set "adr=%adr: =%"` or `set "adr=%adr:~2%"`